# Web Scraping w/Mechanize and/or BeautifulSoup4 on ASP pages

Tags: python, asp.net

Hello I am a programming n00b and am desperately trying to get some code to work.
I can't really find any good tutorials on ASP scraping/filling in fields and submitting then working with the content.

Here is my code so far:

```
import mechanize
import re

url = 'http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/index.asp'
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1)    Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open(url)
response = br.response().read()
```

What I am trying to do:

1. Load that URL
2. Fill out the 2 form fields
3. Submit
4. Print the div id stats into python
5. Run a loop on a 15 minute timer
6. Play a loud sound if anything in div stats changes when it loops

Please advise me the best/fastest way of doing this with minimal programming experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that difficult once you understand why the second form isn't shown when page is loaded. There's nothing to do with ASP itself, it's rather due to CSS style set to **"display: none;"** and will only be active once the first Option Select has been filled.

Here is a full sample of what you're after, implemented in [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), it's similar to machanize I believe.

The basic flow should be:

1. load the web browser and load the page
2. find the first Option Select and fill it in
3. trigger a change event (I chose to send a TAB key) and the second Option Select is shown
4. fill in the second Select and find the submit button and click it
5. assign a name to the content you get from the div id=stats text
6. compared if the text has changed from last fetch

   a) if YES, do your BEEP and close the driver page etc.

   b) if NO, set a scheduler (I use Python's [Event's Scheduler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#module-sched), and run the crawling function again...

That's it! Easy, ok code time -- I used United Kingdom + Working Holiday pair for test:

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import sched, time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/index.asp'
driver.get(url)

html_content = ''
# construct a scheduler
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def crawl_me():
    global html_content
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5s for page to be loaded

    country_name = driver.find_element_by_name('country-name')
    country_name.send_keys('United Kingdom')
    # trick's here to send a TAB key to trigger the change event
    country_name.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

    # make sure the second Option Select is active (none not in style)
    assert "none" not in driver.find_element_by_id('category_dropdown').get_attribute('style')

    cateogory_name = driver.find_element_by_name('category-name')
    cateogory_name.send_keys('Working Holiday')

    btn_go = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
    btn_go.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # again, check if the content has been loaded
    assert "United Kingdom - Working Holiday" not in driver.page_source

    compared_content = driver.find_element_by_id('stats').text
    # here we will end this script if content has changed already
    if html_content != '' and html_content != compared_content:
        # do whatever you want to play the beep sound
        # at the end exit the loop
        driver.close()
        exit(-1)
    # if no changes are found, trigger the schedule_crawl() function, like recursively
    html_content = compared_content
    print html_content
    return schedule_crawl()

def schedule_crawl():
    # set your time interval here, 15*60 = 15 minutes
    s.enter(15*60, 1, crawl_me, ())
    s.run() # and run it of course

crawl_me()
```

To be honest, this is quite easy and straight forward however it does require you fully understand how html/css/javascript (not javascript in this case, but you do need to know the basic) and all their elements how they work together.

You do need to learn from the basic read => digest => code => experience => do it in cycles, **Programming doesn't have a shortcut or the fastest way.**

Hope this helps (and I really hope you do not just copy & paste mine, but learn and implement your own in mechanize by the way).

Good Luck!

Comment: My god... your code is beautiful.
Thank you so much for suggesting Selenium.
That "assert" function = briliant.

Comment: @Ferret not a problem and I'm glad it helps. Everyone does improve by learning and coding, I have been there just like you. Good luck and all the best :)